# Changing name of title name in window of Duplicated layout

Tags: filemaker

I duplicated a layout and now I have two windows with same title in the window.

While not a big deal I do not see a place where I can can the "Title" name of the window, "RP Course List"

[image]

Where's the option to change the Title of the window?

This is using FileMaker AdvancePro 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this by script (or script step), there's an easy way to get at this:

1. In the **New Window** script step, you can programmatically set the new window's "Window Name" property when you create it.
2. Alternately, if the window is already open, you can use the script step "Set Window Title" to do this.

If users can open this window directly (instead of via a script you've written), you might want to create a simple script to set the window's name per above, then set the layout's OnLayoutEnter script trigger to call that script. That way, no matter how the window is displayed, it should get the name you want it to have.